# Assignment from std::make_shared to std::shared_ptr fails silently? (VS2012 Bug)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

EDIT: Renaming the global var did the trick. The same was being reused in other CPP files in the same project. The editor was "confusing" the variable, showing the content of another shared_ptr with the same name!

Thanks for all who answered and tried to help ;)

---

In VS2012 IDE, VS2010 compiler, Debug

When assigning from make_shared, it doesn’t work (shared_ptr stays nullptr).

I can see in the debugger the class ctor was called.

In the header file

```
    struct  ROLLWRKAREA  Workarea
    {
        short idLoc;
// ...
    ROLLWRKAREA(short idLocation=LS_NOWHERE) : 
        idLoc(idLocation),
// …
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<ROLLWRKAREA> LPROLLWRKAREA;
```

In My CPP ->

```
static LPROLLWRKAREA pWA; // ...and pointer

BOOL CRollEx::OnInitDialog ()
{
         CMMDialog::OnInitDialog ();

    pWA = std::make_shared<ROLLWRKAREA>();
```

…
pWA has empty (nullptr) after this line.

Is this expected? Am I doing something stupid here? Is there a workaround? I’m trying to avoid using .reset(new ROLLWRKAREA())

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't begin to express what I think of a type identifier such as `LPROLLWRKAREA`...

Comment: @Angew just noticed that

Comment: Nothing obvious in the (minimal amount of) code you posted. Can you isolate an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) out of your actual code and post that?

Comment: @KerrekSB trying to modernize legacy C code from 1995-2000. Initially was typedef struct _ROLLWRKAREA {...} LPROLLWRKAREA*, ROLLWRKAREA; :P

Comment: @Angew not much more than this - a lot of other basic type vars in the struct that are initialized in the ctor. nothing special here - that's the reason I'm puzzled. BTW: pWA.reset(new ROLLWRKAREA()); also doesn't work. Could it be because it's _static_ ? Could it be because I have other globals (in other CPP files) with the same name (different inner type though)?

Comment: @nCoder Assuming all the other globals are also `static`, that should be fine. Otherwise, I'm fairly certain you'd be violaing ODR and anything could happen.

Answer (score -2):

In the Line
`pWA = std::make_shared<ROLLWRKAREA>();` you need to give something to make shared...
Until then, you get the most sensible you can expect: NULL

Comment: You give constructor arguments to `make_shared`. If you don't give any, then you should get a default-constructed object, not nothing.

Comment: If the constructor called takes no argument it should be fine.

Comment: `std::make_shared<ROLLWRKAREA>()` is the same as doing `std::shared_ptr<ROLLWRKAREA> pWA(new ROLLWRKAREA)`.  That is, supplying nothing to `make_shared` will call the default constructor - not set it to `nullptr`

Comment: This is only another **Visual Stutio Bug**

Comment: The standard guarantees that the value returned by `std::make_shared` will never be a null pointer.  (If the code compiles, doesn't throw an exception, and has no undefined behavior, of course.)